# c++ 11 overloading << (stream insertion) operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, cout

I am trying to overload `<<` operator so that I can use it `cout`. I do not have any class, the code is divided into `test.h/test.cpp` and `main.cpp` files --

first `test.h`:

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

using std::ostream ; using std::vector ;

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const vector<T> &vec);

#endif
```

now `test.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using std::ostream ; using std::cout ; using std::endl ; 
using std::vector ;

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const vector<T> &vec) {
    if(vec.size() > 0) {
        os << "[ " << vec[0] << ", " ;
        for(int i = 1 ; i < vec.size()-1 ; i++) os << vec[i] << ", ";
        os << vec[vec.size()-1] << " ]" ;   
    }
    else
        os << "" ;
    return os ;
}
```

the `main.cpp` looks like this --

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using std::cout ; using std::endl ; 
using std::vector ; using std::string ; using std::to_string ;

int main()
{
   vector<string> vec ;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
       vec.push_back(to_string(i));
   cout << vec << endl ; // printing the vector here
   return 0;
}
```

and I am compiling the code like --

```
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 *.cpp -I. -o test
```

the code is extremely straight forward, nothing complicated, but I am getting this linker error --

```
/tmp/ccczf9Rq.o: In function `main':
/tmp/mdp/main.cpp:18: undefined reference to `std::ostream& operator<< <std::string>(std::ostream&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what is going on?

Comment: You should simply put the implementation into the header file. Template is like macro, and it will not initiate the template in cpp file.

Comment: BTW `_TEST_H_` is **undefined behavior**! Do NOT use an identifier that starts with underscore then upper case letter or an identifier with two underscores in a row.

Comment: @Czipperz could you please elaborate a little bit more? why a single underscore is undefined but a double is not?

Comment: @ramgorur The following are undefined: `_Hi`, `hi__h`, `__x`.  Even `_x` is undefined in the _global namespace_ (so macros count!).  The following are well defined: `_hi`, `hi_i_h`, `hi_h`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier#228797